# Issue For Unique field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working to maintain unique field in Mongodb but its not workig .

Here My code  :

```
 var RepositorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        folderName: { type: String, unique: true},
        tag: String ,
        ismainFolder: { type: Boolean },
        innerFiles:  [{ filename: String, isFolder: { type: Boolean },    parentfolderId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'repository' }, filelocation: { type: String } }],
        innerFolder: [{ foldername: String, ismainFolder: { type: Boolean }, parentfolderId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'repository' } }],
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('repository', RepositorySchema);
```

FolderName is not maintaining Unique Values , please help me

Comment: Can you add some records that you retrieved from the database, and that have the same `folderName` value, to your question?

Comment: Is there already data in the collection? Chances are it is not in fact all "unique" and creation of the index fails for that reason. Turn on debugging with `mongoose.set('debug',true)` and see what logs when your application is started. There should be an error when it attempts to create the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to recreate all indexes on your collection. Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
> mongo
> use <your_dv>
> db.repository.reIndex()
```

> The reIndex command drops all indexes on a collection and recreates them. This operation may be expensive for collections that have a large amount of data and/or a large number of indexes.

Comment: Won't work if duplicates are already present, which is the likely cause.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, it could be an issue, but sometimes mongoose doesn't apply unique index on existing collection, even when there are no duplicates. Indexes recreation can help.

Comment: Well "could" from my perspective is based on seeing the same thing asked a couple of hundred times. 99% Of those cases is the index does not exist because creation failed due to duplicates. Mongoose "re-indexes" on application startup by default anyway. So you are not actually telling the OP anything of benefit here. Understand now?